# Embed asset in a Flex library project, then override in main application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex3, embedded-resource

I've developed some code that I want to use in all future (web based) Flex projects. (I'm stuck at Flex 3.5 for infrastructure reasons.)

As part of its operation it reads an XML file to find project specific information.

When I moved the code from a project into a library, obviously it fell over trying to find the xml asset (using 'embed' in an Actionscript class.)

My hope was to embed a default XML file in the library which would be overridden at runtime in  the project itself.

Problem: Even though I've included the asset file in the library file structure and added it in 'project properties/flex library build path/assets' I'm getting an 'unable to resolve' error. How do I fix it?

Question: Assuming I get it to work, if I place an asset in the same location in the project including the library, will it override it? (If not, is there another way of accomplishing this kind of behaviour?)

Thanks!